# Dúvida com JOINS e GROUP BY numa query SQL (Access)

Tags: sql, query, join, microsoft-access, inner-join

desde já agradeço pela ajuda.
Não sou muito avançado nos SQL e estou enfrentando uma dificuldade aqui, é o seguinte:

```
SELECT tbl_afs_pregao.numaf, 
       tbl_items_pregao.nomeitem, 
       Sum(tbl_items_af.qtd) AS SomaDeQtd, 
       tbl_items_pregao.id_itempregao 
FROM   (tbl_afs_pregao 
        INNER JOIN tbl_items_af 
                ON tbl_afs_pregao.id_af = tbl_items_af.id_af) 
       INNER JOIN tbl_items_pregao 
               ON tbl_items_af.id_itempregao = tbl_items_pregao.id_itempregao 
GROUP  BY tbl_afs_pregao.numaf, 
          tbl_items_pregao.nomeitem, 
          tbl_items_pregao.id_itempregao;
```

O resultado é esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A questão é que eu queria agrupar os resultados daqueles items, SUNPATIENS pela soma da quantidade, mas não to conseguindo (1 horinha quase tentando e já deu rs).

Agradeço a todos,

Abraço

Comment: Você está agrupando também por `tbl_afs_pregao.numaf` e as 2 linhas de `SUNPATIENS` mostradas possuem valores diferentes para este campo (1374/2020 e 1522/2020).